# Positioning of a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-styles, graphs

I have two tikz pictures in a figure. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node (a1) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_1$] {}
    -- ++(252:1.2cm)  node (a2) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_2$] {}
    -- ++(324:1.2cm)  node (a3) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt,label=left:$a_3$] {}
    -- ++(36:1.2cm)  node (a4) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_4$] {}
    -- ++(108:1.2cm)  node (a5) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=above:$a_5$] {}
    -- (a1); 
\draw (0.75,-2.2) node (aux1)[minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{};
\draw (4,0)  node (b3) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_3$] {}
    -- ++(216:1.2cm)  node (b2) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_2$] {}
    -- ++(288:1.2cm)  node (b1) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=below:$b_1$] {}
    -- ++(0:1.2cm)  node (b5) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_5$] {}
    -- ++(72:1.2cm)  node (b4) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_4$] {}
    -- (b3);
\draw (4,0.4) node (aux2)[minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{};
\draw (a1) -- (a3);
\draw (a5) -- (a3);
\draw (b3) -- (b1);
\draw (b3) -- (b5);
\draw (a5) -- (b2);
\draw (a4) -- (b1);
\draw (a2) to [out=-80,in=180] (aux1);
\draw (aux1) to [out=0,in=-100] (a4);
\draw (a2) to [out=-90,in=-110] (b5);
\draw (b2) to [out=90,in=180] (aux2);
\draw (aux2) to [out=-10,in=110] (b4);
%\draw (b2) to [out=80,in=100] (b4);
\draw (a1) to [out=70,in=90] (b4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0.3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt]
\draw (0,0) node (3) [label=above:$3$] {}
    -- ++(216:1.2cm) node (2) [label=left:$2$] {}
    -- ++(288:1.2cm) node (1) [label=left:$1$] {}
    -- ++(0:1.2cm) node (5) [label=right:$5$] {}
    -- ++(72:1.2cm) node (4) [label=right:$4$] {}
    -- (3);
\draw (1) -- (3);
\draw (1) -- (4);
\draw (2) -- (4);
\draw (2) -- (5);
\draw (3) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

As you can see the drawings stand not side by side, the second is a little below the first. 
So if anyone has time to answer please suggest me a possible solution. How can I have the three pentagons side by side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `baseline` key to both tikz pictures.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \draw (0,0) node (a1) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_1$] {}
        -- ++(252:1.2cm)  node (a2) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_2$] {}
        -- ++(324:1.2cm)  node (a3) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt,label=left:$a_3$] {}
        -- ++(36:1.2cm)  node (a4) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_4$] {}
        -- ++(108:1.2cm)  node (a5) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=above:$a_5$] {}
        -- (a1); 
        \draw (0.75,-2.2) node (aux1)[minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{};
        \draw (4,0)  node (b3) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_3$] {}
        -- ++(216:1.2cm)  node (b2) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_2$] {}
        -- ++(288:1.2cm)  node (b1) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=below:$b_1$] {}
        -- ++(0:1.2cm)  node (b5) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_5$] {}
        -- ++(72:1.2cm)  node (b4) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_4$] {}
        -- (b3);
        \draw (4,0.4) node (aux2)[minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{};
        \draw (a1) -- (a3);
        \draw (a5) -- (a3);
        \draw (b3) -- (b1);
        \draw (b3) -- (b5);
        \draw (a5) -- (b2);
        \draw (a4) -- (b1);
        \draw (a2) to [out=-80,in=180] (aux1);
        \draw (aux1) to [out=0,in=-100] (a4);
        \draw (a2) to [out=-90,in=-110] (b5);
        \draw (b2) to [out=90,in=180] (aux2);
        \draw (aux2) to [out=-10,in=110] (b4);
        %\draw (b2) to [out=80,in=100] (b4);
        \draw (a1) to [out=70,in=90] (b4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{0.3cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt]
        \draw (0,0) node (3) [label=above:$3$] {}
        -- ++(216:1.2cm) node (2) [label=left:$2$] {}
        -- ++(288:1.2cm) node (1) [label=left:$1$] {}
        -- ++(0:1.2cm) node (5) [label=right:$5$] {}
        -- ++(72:1.2cm) node (4) [label=right:$4$] {}
        -- (3);
        \draw (1) -- (3);
        \draw (1) -- (4);
        \draw (2) -- (4);
        \draw (2) -- (5);
        \draw (3) -- (5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Or draw both figures inside same `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \draw (0,0) node (a1) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_1$] {}
        -- ++(252:1.2cm)  node (a2) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_2$] {}
        -- ++(324:1.2cm)  node (a3) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt,label=left:$a_3$] {}
        -- ++(36:1.2cm)  node (a4) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=left:$a_4$] {}
        -- ++(108:1.2cm)  node (a5) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=above:$a_5$] {}
        -- (a1); 
        \draw (0.75,-2.2) node (aux1)[minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{};
        \draw (4,0)  node (b3) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_3$] {}
        -- ++(216:1.2cm)  node (b2) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_2$] {}
        -- ++(288:1.2cm)  node (b1) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=below:$b_1$] {}
        -- ++(0:1.2cm)  node (b5) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_5$] {}
        -- ++(72:1.2cm)  node (b4) [draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, label=right:$b_4$] {}
        -- (b3);
        \draw (4,0.4) node (aux2)[minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{};
        \draw (a1) -- (a3);
        \draw (a5) -- (a3);
        \draw (b3) -- (b1);
        \draw (b3) -- (b5);
        \draw (a5) -- (b2);
        \draw (a4) -- (b1);
        \draw (a2) to [out=-80,in=180] (aux1);
        \draw (aux1) to [out=0,in=-100] (a4);
        \draw (a2) to [out=-90,in=-110] (b5);
        \draw (b2) to [out=90,in=180] (aux2);
        \draw (aux2) to [out=-10,in=110] (b4);
        %\draw (b2) to [out=80,in=100] (b4);
        \draw (a1) to [out=70,in=90] (b4);
%        \end{tikzpicture}
%        \hspace{0.3cm}
%        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw node[right=3cm of b3] (3) [label=above:$3$] {} (3)
        -- ++(216:1.2cm) node (2) [label=left:$2$] {}
        -- ++(288:1.2cm) node (1) [label=left:$1$] {}
        -- ++(0:1.2cm) node (5) [label=right:$5$] {}
        -- ++(72:1.2cm) node (4) [label=right:$4$] {}
        -- (3);
        \draw (1) -- (3);
        \draw (1) -- (4);
        \draw (2) -- (4);
        \draw (2) -- (5);
        \draw (3) -- (5);
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** (and not related with previous answer)

Just for fun here you find another solution for previous figure.

I've used `regular polygons` nodes and their already defined anchors. This way it's easier to use relative placement for them. Two right pentagonal nodes use `transform shape, xscale=-1` to revert corners order to be CW.

Labels on vertex are placed with three `foreach` constructions.

And `aux1` and `aux2` nodes has been eliminated by adding some `control` points in `to` constructions. Hope it helps.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={circle, fill=white, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, draw}]
            \node[draw, regular polygon, shape border rotate=36, minimum size=2cm, anchor=corner 1] (a) {};
            \draw (a.corner 3) edge (a.corner 1) edge (a.corner 5);

            \node[draw, regular polygon, shape border rotate=216, minimum size=2cm,  right=4cm of a.corner 1, anchor=corner 3, transform shape, xscale=-1] (b) {};
            \draw (b.corner 3) edge (b.corner 1) edge (b.corner 5);

            \node[draw, regular polygon, shape border rotate=216, minimum size=2cm,  right=4cm of b.corner 3, anchor=corner 3, transform shape, xscale=-1] (c) {};
            \foreach \i/\j in  {1/3,2/4,3/5,4/1,5/2}
                \draw (c.corner \i) edge (c.corner \j);

            \foreach \i [count=\ni] in  {left, left, left, left, above}
                \node[vertex, label=\i:{$a_\ni$}] (a\ni) at (a.corner \ni) {};

            \foreach \i [count=\ni] in  {below, right, right, right, right}
                \node[vertex, label=\i:{$b_\ni$}] (b\ni) at (b.corner \ni) {};

            \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {left,left,above,right,right}
                \node[vertex, label=\i:{$\ni$}] (c\ni) at (c.corner \ni) {};

        \draw (a5) -- (b2);
        \draw (a4) -- (b1);
        \draw (a2) to [controls=+(-90:1.2) and +(-90:1.2), out=-80,in=-110] (a4);
        \draw (a2) to [out=-90,in=-110] (b5);
        \draw (b2) to [controls=+(90:1.2) and +(90:1.2), out=90,in=110] (b4);
        \draw (a1) to [out=70,in=90] (b4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hesitate proposing such a solution!